# MVC 3. Update jquery.validate. Client-side validation is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, client-side

mvc 3 after updating jquery.validate-1.8 to jquery.validate-1.11 client-side validation is not working.
use:

- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js
- jquery.validate.js (jquery.validate-1.11)
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js (Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive
  Validation 2.0.30116.0)
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
  (Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax 2.0.30116.0)

client-side validation is working for following libraries:
use:

- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js
- jquery.validate.js (jquery.validate-1.8)
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js (Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation 2.0.30116.0)
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js (Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax
    2.0.30116.0)

How do I upgrade?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jquery ui autocomplete combobox which hid the tag select.
by default in 1.8 is not to ignore the hidden fields.
older versions be ignored.
To solve the problem, use:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
   ignore: []
});
```